# Angular url handling - order of '#' and '?'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Angular 1.0.8 handles correctly this url `http://server.com/#angular-fragment?param=value`. $routeParams corerctly parses the url.

but when i use a welcome url: `http://server.com?param=value` angular redirects to `http://server.com/?param=value#angular-fragment` and $routeParams doesn't work any more.

is it possible to make angular correctly handles such url's or do i have to do redirect before angular kicks in?

Comment: Why don't you use welcome url like this `http://server.com/#fragment?param=value`

Comment: because it's out of my control. besides, is it invalid url?